# Allow my users to map their own subdomains to my service

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess

I'm trying to create a landing page service similar to Leadpages. Basically my user needs to be able to map their subdomain, lets say "offer.domain.com" to my domain, so they can access their landing pages using their own domains. They need to be able to do this on the fly, without me going in to touch anything on my end.

How would I begin to approach this? Not sure where to start.

If it helps, I'm on PHP, mysql, Yii2 framework.

EDIT: To be clear, this subdomain is owned by the user, not by me.

Comment: Have your tried https://blog.serverdensity.com/apache-wildcard-subdomains-examplecom/ ?

Comment: @KostyaShkryob I meant each user will be using their own domain, not mine.